# When was the ability to declare a variable in the if statement introduced in C++?

Tags: c++

In C++, we can declare variables directly in the if statement and its value is used as the condition, e.g.

```cpp
if (SubClass *subObject = dynamic_cast<SubClass *>(baseObject)) {
    // ...
}
```

For some reason, I always assumed that this was a "relatively" new feature, introduced in C++11 at the earliest, but when I tried to confirm this, I found no information about this, only that C++17 expands the syntax even further. When I tried compiling a minimal example with `-std=c++98`, it worked. So has this been a feature of C++ from the beginning?

Comment: cppref is usually a rather good reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if.

Comment: `When I tried compiling a minimal example with -std=c++98, it worked` What what compiler?

Comment: It was introduced in C++17.   Some compilers supported it as a non-standard extension before that.

Comment: @KamilCuk `g++` on Linux

Comment: @Peter OP writes not `if (T a = b; a)` but `if (T a = b)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first *formal* C++ Standard was ISO/IEC 14882:1998 (a.k.a. C++98). In [this 'draft' version of that](http://www.lirmm.fr/%7Educour/Doc-objets/ISO+IEC+14882-1998.pdf), the declaration of a variable inside an `if` statement is explicitly mentioned:

> #### 6.4 Selection statements       [stmt.select]
>
> …
> 3      A name
> introduced by a declaration in a condition (either introduced by the
> type-specifier-seq or the declarator of the condition) is in scope
> from its point of declaration until the end of the substatements
> controlled by the condition. If the name is re-declared in the
> outermost block of a substatement controlled by the condition, the
> declaration that re-declares the name is ill-formed. *[Example:*
>
> ```
> if (int x = f()) {
>             int x; // ill-formed, redeclaration of x
> } else { 
>             int x; // ill-formed, redeclaration of x
> }
> ```
>
> *—end example]*

So, in terms of formal Standards: Yes, it's "been there since the beginning."

Comment: I'd **love** to have a copy of the *first edition* of Bjarne Stroustrups's book, so I could check in there (for the real, "since the beginning"). Alas, I'm not so lucky. If anyone passing through does possess such a gem, please feel free to comment, edit, or post a better answer.